# Design a program to download a facebook group data

Tags: design, uml, facebook

I have a study facebook group which has a lot of information. The  size is about ~10k post and 30k comments/replies etc... making it very hard to search on facebook itself.

So I am trying to dump the data to a csv file, or an sqlite database. Here's the design:

The entities:

[image]

The flow to download:

[image]

How to update:

[image]

**How is this design while processing large data?**

Answer (score 0):

I would change the domain classes.

Classes:

- Post.
- Comment (used for subcomments too).

Or everything can be considered as posts or messages if having the same fields.

You can change the static Utils class into a instance of service so it can be swappable and tested.

Answer (score -1):

You have 10K posts and 30K comments and you are primarily scrapping this data for better searching capability.

First things first : SQL is not good for natural query searching for example if someone searches for "Which college is good" it tries to search for the exact string from you SQL and it might not match any of the records.

I would suggest you to use SOLR or Elastic search for your requirement. SOLR and Elastic Search provides a lot of functionality to clean your data and provide natural queries for searching the content (it is more like hosting google search on your local machine). In SOLR you can create a document and put content inside it, here the document is your post and content is the comments inside the post. This is much more scalable and provides you with more relevant results than using native SQL queries for searching the content.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. SOLR is completely new to me. Do you have any comments on the diagrams?